# How can I get predicted the following value of stock using predict method of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I am wondering how to predict and get future time series data after model training. I would like to get the values after N steps. I wonder if the time series data has been properly learned and predicted. How do I do this right to get the following(next) value? I want to get the next value using `model.predict` or similar.

I have `x_test` and `x_test[-1] == t` So, the meaning of the next value is `t+1, t+2, .... t+n`. In this example **I want to get `t+1, t+2 ... t+n`**

## First

I tried using stock index data

```
inputs = total_data[len(total_data) - forecast - look_back:]
inputs = scaler.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(look_back, inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i - look_back:i])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

but the result is like below

[image]

The results from `X_test[-20:]` and the following 20 **predictions looks like same.** I'm wondering if it's the correct method to train and predicted value and also if the result was correct.

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/2e1759a0e435ff95b7a017e301db634f)

The method I tried first did not work correctly.

## Second

I realized something is wrong, I tried using another official data so I used the time series in the **Tensorflow tutorial** to practice training the model.

```
a = y_val[-look_back:] 
for i in range(N-step prediction): #predict a new value n times.
    tmp = model.predict(a.reshape(-1, look_back, num_feature)) #predicted value     
    a = a[1:] #remove first     
    a = np.append(a, tmp) #insert predicted value
```

The results were predicted in a linear regression shape very differently from the real data.

[image: 2]

Output a linear regression abnormal that is independent of the real data:

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/96e0ba8d8c251046e89eae4bc5d40510)  (After the 25th line is my code.)

I'm really very curious that **How can I predict the following value of time series using Tensorflow predict method**

I'm not wondering if this works or not theoretically. I'm just wondering how to **get the following n steps using the predict method.**

Thank you for reading the long question. I seek advice about your priceless opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In the Second approach, Output is not expected, as per my understanding, because of a small mistake in the code.

The line of code,

```
a = y_val[-look_back:]
```

should be replaced by

```
look_back = 20
x = x_val_uni
a = x[-look_back:]
a.shape
```

In other words, we should send `X Values` as Inputs to the Model for the Prediction, not the `Y Values`.

However, we can compare it's predictions with Y Values, with the code,

```
y = y_val_uni[-20:]

plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(tmp)
plt.show()
```

Which would result in the plot shown below:

[image]

Please find the Complete Working Code in this [Google Colab Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/f1999818e9a35183f2c100087ce7dc7b/time_series_prediction.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you. How can I predict the next 20 values?